# making strict to javascript language

Tags: javascript

Javascript is loosely typed language but can we strict this?

```
var myVar = "string";
......
//later on
myVar = 123;//changed to number
```

So, now I want that if myVar is changed to "somestring", "anystring" would be okay. But if myVar is changed to number like 123 then the previously defined string in myVar should return as the result.

Comment: Not without some wrapper objects to check for types.

Comment: [TAJS](http://www.brics.dk/TAJS/) (Type Analyzer for JavaScript) might be useful. Never used it myself though.

Answer (score 2):

No, wrong language. But you can try programming in [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

On browsers that support it, you can use `Object.defineProperty()`<sup>[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)</sup> with custom `get` and `set` functions to achieve this effect:

```
function def(obj, prop, cond) {
    Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, {
        get: function() {
            return obj["_" + prop];
        },
        set: function(value) {
            if (cond(value)) {
                obj["_" + prop] = value;
            }
        }
    });
}

function str(value) {
    return typeof value === 'string' || value instanceof String;
}

def(window, 'myVar', str);

myVar = "something";
myVar = "anything";
myVar = 42;
myVar; // => "anything"
```

This can be used to define typed global variables (as in the example) and object properties, but not local variables or function parameters.